# My next.js website crashes losing all the content except cryptic <pre /> element in the <body /> tag

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I leave the site open in the Chrome tab and return after a few days, I notice that the website loses all the content, showing only cryptic messages in the `<pre />` tag. Does anyone know why this happens and how to stop the behavior?

```
1:HL["/_next/static/css/af9c9d9f249ead4f.css",{"as":"style"}]
0:[[["",{"children":["service",{"children":["jobs",{"children":["__PAGE__",{}]}]}]},"$undefined","$undefined",true],"$L2",[[["$","link","0",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/af9c9d9f249ead4f.css","precedence":"next"}]],["$L3",["$","meta",null,{"name":"next-size-adjust"}]]]]]
4:I{"id":"6712","chunks":["656:static/chunks/656-50587f6da2bb03a2.js","941:static/chunks/941-419b4e40e05d9514.js","487:static/chunks/487-5a1c36a130145f71.js","535:static/chunks/535-16359f4f272ce5e6.js","908:static/chunks/908-0388e2ce9a4147ff.js","517:static/chunks/517-85b51e85485bbcc6.js","185:static/chunks/app/layout-326f799529ab3429.js"],"name":"","async":false}
5:I{"id":"9544","chunks":["272:static/chunks/webpack-3010d274fdba2749.js","667:static/chunks/2443530c-425c30f31d455821.js","139:static/chunks/139-bf3c26bdf7922621.js"],"name":"","async":false}
6:I{"id":"99","chunks":["272:static/chunks/webpack-3010d274fdba2749.js","667:static/chunks/2443530c-425c30f31d455821.js","139:static/chunks/139-bf3c26bdf7922621.js"],"name":"","async":false}
7:I{"id":"9457","chunks":["272:static/chunks/webpack-3010d274fdba2749.js","667:static/chunks/2443530c-425c30f31d455821.js","139:static/chunks/139-bf3c26bdf7922621.js"],"name":"","async":false}
8:I{"id":"8386","chunks":["656:static/chunks/656-50587f6da2bb03a2.js","941:static/chunks/941-419b4e40e05d9514.js","677:static/chunks/677-626181be93b098f2.js","487:static/chunks/487-5a1c36a130145f71.js","676:static/chunks/676-c0494fa753758eaa.js","153:static/chunks/app/service/jobs/page-1663fa4a8f96b7a7.js"],"name":"","async":false}
2:[["$","$L4",null,{"children":["$","$L5",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children"],"error":"$undefined","errorStyles":"$undefined","loading":"$undefined","loadingStyles":"$undefined","hasLoading":false,"template":["$","$L6",null,{}],"templateStyles":"$undefined","notFound":"$undefined","notFoundStyles":"$undefined","asNotFound":"$undefined","childProp":{"current":["$","$L5",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children","service","children"],"error":"$undefined","errorStyles":"$undefined","loading":"$undefined","loadingStyles":"$undefined","hasLoading":false,"template":["$","$L6",null,{}],"templateStyles":"$undefined","notFound":"$undefined","notFoundStyles":"$undefined","asNotFound":"$undefined","childProp":{"current":["$","$L5",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children","service","children","jobs","children"],"error":"$undefined","errorStyles":"$undefined","loading":"$undefined","loadingStyles":"$undefined","hasLoading":false,"template":["$","$L6",null,{}],"templateStyles":"$undefined","notFound":"$undefined","notFoundStyles":"$undefined","asNotFound":"$undefined","childProp":{"current":[["$","$L7",null,{"propsForComponent":{"params":{}},"Component":"$8"}],null],"segment":"__PAGE__"},"styles":[]}],"segment":"jobs"},"styles":[]}],"segment":"service"},"styles":[]}],"params":{}}],null]
3:[[["$","meta",null,{"charSet":"utf-8"}],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,["$","meta",null,{"name":"viewport","content":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]],[null,null,null,null],null,null,[null,null,null,null,null],null,null,null,null,null]
```